# Single signin/signup system for whole project

Tags: php, authentication, oauth

I have an idea and going to realise it

My idea is simple: my website will be for examination purposes. There will be a page for questions and answers like stackoverflow (http://www.question2answer.org),  users will disguss their questions and their user database will be single. And registration, login system will suppport oauth.

Now, the main question is, i want to create single signin/signup system for whole project (website and q2a) which will support Facebook/google signin/signup (oauth). I dunno where to start, the creation of whole website (quiz system) is not difficult for me but merging registration systems - hard. That's why I stucked: only thinking about how will i do it?! Can you help me to create the plan of the work? Please give me hints

Thx in advance for any suggestion, advise.. I will be gratefull for any help

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to looking to Sessions. A quick look for some basics:

Facebook: [Facebook Sessions](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/)

Google: [OpenID](http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/OpenID.html)

Basically you include the relevant session data and then you can pull things such as usernames and such. It's a big question you're asking which isn't really defined enough but I hope that'll get you looking in the right direction for merging login systems.